# Curve $\Gamma$ is parametrized by $\Gamma(u)=(u+\sqrt3\sin u,2\cos u,\sqrt 3u-\sin u)$. Find circular helix & isometry $T$ with $T_{\gamma}=\Gamma$.

Tags: curves, parametrization, isometry

**Question**

> The curve $\Gamma$ is parametrized by $$\Gamma(u)=(u+\sqrt3\sin u,2\cos u, \sqrt 3u-\sin u)$$  Find a circular helix and an isometry $T$ such that $T_{\gamma}=\Gamma$.

I have tried to compare the parametrizations to the general form of a circular helix but didn't get anywhere. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to find a circle helix using that parametrization and an isometry T